# InApp Purchase - How to detect when Alert 'Confirm Your In App Purchase' is displayed

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, uiactivityindicatorview

I have my store all setup, everything is working perfectly.

What i'm trying to do now is when they click on a button to buy something from my app, i'm displaying a custom UIActivityIndicator type thing to show the users that things are actually loading (and to stop them from going back in case the alert takes 10+ secs to show up).

I have a timeout set to perform after a 30s delay to hide the ActivityIndicator incase the store isn't responding so the users won't be stuck waiting forever.
All this is working fine.

The problem is when the 'Confirm Your In App Purchase' Alert is displayed, i'm not sure how to get notified that it appeared so i can hide the ActivityIndicator I have still running in the back.

There are methods to detect when the user hits Cancel or Buy which I have but I would like to hide the ActivityIndicator before they hit one so the users don't see it in the background while they read it.

Did I overlook a delegate that would work for this?
Or will I have to write something custom to make this work the way I want?

Thanks!

---

I also tried implementing the UIAlertViewDelegate with this method however it doens't catch the In-App Purchase alert views :(

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView;
```

---

In case anyone else is interested in a solution I made up.

When you call load and start connecting to your store you can add an  observer to catch when your phone will resign being active. This way  when the In App alert appears the method you choose gets called and you  can cancel your activity monitor.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(inAppAlertAppeared:) 
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: I think that's as good a solution as any.  Nice work.

Comment: Nice solution, but may I ask how you know when the user clicks 'Buy'? That's is what I am struggling with right now.

Comment: In your In App Purchase manager class in the (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productIdentifier method you can post to NSNotificationCenter. From what I recall that methods only gets called once the user actually buy's something.

Answer (score -2):

Check the following link 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases
it may help you

Comment: I didn't read through this but Ray Wenderlich usually has great tutorials so I'm sure it's good as well!

Comment: Don't post links by themselves in attempt to answer questions

Comment: The link is just a tutorial for IAP programming. It does not really answer the question.